# rsync delete files that were synced before only

Tags: ubuntu, rsync, deployment

**Goal:**
I want to copy a local repository to a remote server. This includes new, modified, and deleted files.

**Problem:**
`rsync --delete` will delete (on the destination) anything that is not present in the source (my repo). However I have important files on the server that are not in my repo (media, assets, config files..etc). So I want to keep those files, but delete any files that were synced before using rsync.

**In other words**, anything that was in my repo and I deleted should be deleted from the server, but other files on my server should not be deleted.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for rsync to distinguish between files that existed before you ever ran rsync and files that were created after, unless you can ensure a modified date.  Your best bet would be to use either a different directory for the repo or use filters, include/exclude and include-file/exclude-file.  All of these options can be found in the rsync manpage or with a simple search using your favorite search engine.